# jQuery selector not working for table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying with jquery to add classes to only the cells with active_square already as a class. But this line never works. Is the selector wrong?

```
 $("table#team_a_grid > tr > td.active_square").addClass('clickable');   
   <table border='1' id="team_a_grid" style="float:left;">
     <tr>
       <td class=''></td>
        <td class=''>A</td>
        <td class=''>B</td>
        <td class=''>C</td>
        <td class=''>D</td>
        <td class=''>E</td>
        <td class='active_square'>F</td>
        <td class='active_square'>G</td>
        <td class='active_square'>H</td>
        <td class='active_square'>I</td>
        <td class='active_square'>J</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers will insert a `tbody` element to make the table valid

```
$("#team_a_grid > tbody > tr > td.active_square").addClass('clickable');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P8k7k/)

Unless you really have nested tables you're better of using

```
$("#team_a_grid td.active_square").addClass('clickable');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find to find all td's in the table and add the class:

```
$("#team_a_grid").find("td.active_square").addClass('clickable');
```

Comment: oops sorry didn't notice the  active_square bit... will ammend answer

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough to just check on active_square ? Makes it general for other tables as well.

```
$("td.active_square").addClass('clickable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("table#team_a_grid tr td.active_square").addClass('clickable');
```

In jquery you can select children by giving an space between parent and children.

But the good practice we be using `.find()` method of jquery as

```
$("table#team_a_grid").find(".active_square").addClass('clickable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out your class within the context. This is the faster way to do this easily:

```
$("td.active_square", "#team_a_grid").addClass("clickable");
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xpmTN/1/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use Code This

$('table  tr  td.active_square').addClass('clickable')

Answer (score 0):

place this in the  of your page and you're good

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table#team_a_grid td.active_square").addClass('clickable');
)}
</script>
```